# How to use chart control in mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I want to use Chart in my MVC Dashboard form.

I have used following code.

```
@{
        var key = new Chart(width: 300, height: 300)
          .AddTitle("Employee Chart")
          .AddSeries(
              chartType: "Bubble",
              name: "Employee",
              xValue: new[] { "Peter", "Andrew", "Julie", "Dave" },
              yValues: new[] { "2", "7", "5", "3" });     
    }
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>Test</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div> 
            <div>
                @key.Write()
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

but `@key.Write()` writes chart in whole page but I want it in partial form not in whole form with other content in Dashboard page.
Can anybody help me for this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Move your chart code to controller action like this:

```
    public ActionResult GetChartImage()
    {
        var key = new Chart(width: 300, height: 300)
            .AddTitle("Employee Chart")
            .AddSeries(
            chartType: "Bubble",
            name: "Employee",
            xValue: new[] { "Peter", "Andrew", "Julie", "Dave" },
            yValues: new[] { "2", "7", "5", "3" });

        return File(key.ToWebImage().GetBytes(), "image/jpeg");
    }
```

(include using System.Web.Helpers namespace) and modify your view:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div> 
        <div>
            <img src="@Url.Action("GetChartImage")" />
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: how can i set Y Axis Interval value in this chart?

Comment: you can't do this, at least not very easily. You might have some luck setting theme http://truncatedcodr.wordpress.com/2012/09/18/system-web-helpers-chart-custom-themes/ but consider using some better charting library, Chart class is simple but very limited